# IT infrastructure management software

Tags: cloud-service

Before I dive deep into my question I want to apologize if I am asking this question on the wrong platform.

I am looking for a solution that provides me following

1. Inventory management
2. Control over inventory (To be able to manage them via portal)
3. Access Control to inventory via Active directory or something like
   that
4. Network Monitoring
5. Capacity Planning
6. Access Logs to Servers/Machines
7. Wholistic view of data center (Cloud based datacenter, Hybrid cloud,
   and physical machines)

The solution can be paid or open source. 
I tried to search few but not sure if they really are reliable etc.

Comment: Noone can help me on this ?